# How to act upon several API requests when they success

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, frontend

I want to ask about the best practice to take an action upon several API request calls.

My use case is as following:

I have an endpoint that upload single file to server, but I'm allowing to attach multiple files on the interface. For each file there will be an API call to upload this file to the server. After all these files success uploading I want to make the another API call that will tell the user some results of what he did.

So for my implementation which I don't know if it's the best/good or not,

I just made smth looks like this (which doesn't guarantee that these calls have succeeded)

```
attachedFiles.forEach(file => dispatch(uploadFileToServer(file)) //uploading file to server)
showResults(); //this is the second api call
```

But what I actually want to happen is something more to

```
   attachedFiles.forEach(file => distpatch(uploadFileToServer(file)))
     .then(()=> showResults())
```

so by this I think I'll be sure that they all succeeded.

I'm using

ReactJs, ReduxToolKit

Answer (score 0):

use `Promise.all` like below :

```
Promise.all(attachedFiles.map(file => uploadFileToServer(file)).then(()=>{
    showResults()
})
```

Comment: would this work with reduxtoolkit ? as dispatching these api calls